# Can the light and dark theme options in Gnome Control Center be configured?

Tags: themes, system-settings, 21.10

In the Appearance tab of System Settings, we can select between light and dark themes.

In Ubuntu 21.10, this selects the Yaru Light them or the Yaru Dark theme, respectively.

Can this control be configured to select a different theme (that has a light and dark variant)? If so, how?

[image: Gnome Control Center - Themes]